# Twilio client JS calls duration limited?

Tags: twilio

I've set up a Twilio app to record students reading as a tool for reading therapists using our service.  I set up the TwiML callbacks, set up the app in my Twilio account, and it all works wonderfully - when I use a real phone.

When I use the Twilio client javacript library, the recording cuts off at exactly one minute.  This does not happen when using a real phone.  I'm very puzzled.

Here's the requisite TwiML for the record verb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman">Please read what you have been assigned .  When you are done, click the hang up button.  Start reading after the beep!</Say>
    <Pause length="2"/>
    <Record timeout="15" action="save?assignment=51273&amp;softphone=true&amp;date=2015-11-09" maxLength="3600"/>
    <Say>Sorry, I did not hear a recording.  Goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

So you can see, I'm setting the Record verb's maxLength explicitly to 3600, which should give us up to a hour's recording.  Anyone have any idea why the javacript client-initiated calls are getting hung up on automatically?  I don't see any errors on the client side, it just cleanly hangs up.  No errors in my event log in my Twilio dash either.  I'm stumped!

It should be noted I'm on Firefox using WebRTC (the default) for the client library test.

Answer (score 0):

Megan from Twilio here.

Your TwiML looks fine. I would suggest that you make sure you can record at that length in the example given for Twilio Client Recordings:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/twilio-client-record

Explicitly turn debugging on if you haven't already:

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, {debug: true});
```

If all else fails, you can email help@twilio.com with the CallSid of calls that are displaying this behavior and they will be able to dig into what is going on.

I hope this helps.